# XPages send doc via email

Tags: email, xpages

I want to add the option to my application to send the current document via email to another person.
And in the email to be a button which when clicked will redirect the user to the document.

Thank you,

Florin

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You need to try on your own as best as you can and then come to Stack Over Flow when you are stuck on something more specific.  We can't do the work for you.  I will say however, that there are a lot of Snippets on OpenNTF.org.  There's an email bean snippet that people have used. There may be others. For best results, try to find it and apply it and if you have a specific problem then come back here.

Comment: Is the question on how to send an email or how to have a button embedded in the body of a mail message.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the sendMail simple action. A quick example:

```
<xp:button value="Send Mail" id="button1">  
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:sendMail to="aadmin/xpages@xpages" subject="Test mail" from="myaddress@example.org">
                <xp:this.bodyHtml><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
                     return "Visit my page: " + context.getUrl();}]]>
                </xp:this.bodyHtml>
            </xp:sendMail>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

In the bodyHtml property, you can create the necessary HTML for a button there.